# How to design a protocol between Java server and Java workers on top of HTTP?

Tags: java, http, architecture, client-server, communication

This is a design (architecture) question. Suppose there is a Java server, which processes client requests. The processing includes *steps* that are performed by external Java processes *workers* rather than the server itself.

That is, we have a server and a few *worker* processes: a few *workers* that perform *step A* , a few workers that perform *step B* and *step C*, etc.

Suppose also that the server and all workers communicate with HTTP. Now I wonder how to design a protocol for the communication between the server and *workers* .

Currently I am thinking of the following:

- when a *worker* is ready to work it sends an HTTP GET request to the server. The request contains the worker ID (his host + PID), status, and *steps*: e.g `worker_status=READY, host=localhost, pid=1234, steps=A`
- when there is a *step* to perform the server sends a response with the step name, input data and the deadline : `step=A, deadline=..., data=...`
- when a *worker* finishes processing, it sends an HTTP GET request to the server. The request contains the step name, processing status and output data `finished_step=A, status=SUCCESS, output=...` and the information as in the first message (see above): , `worker_status=READY, host=localhost, pid=1234, steps=A`

Does it make sense? Is there any existing well-known protocols for that kind communication between a server and worker processes ?

Comment: Does it have to be over HTTP? Why don't you use something that's already there, like JMS or the like?

Comment: Yes, we can introduce a _new_ separate entity (e.g. JMS with ActiveMQ) etc. and add it to the system. Now I wonder if we _really_ need it. I would prefer a _simpler_ and _lighter_ solution without all that complex stuff.

Comment: The nice thing about using a jms or message queue to solve this would be that your design would be much simpler not more complex.   Server would push the work into a queue or queues and forget them in that context.   Whatever worker that is that is ready and capable would pick up job.   This is specially useful when you have workers down busy or being updated.

Comment: @ArashSharif. Thanks. Could please you give an example of what JMS does and my design does not? I am sure JMS has a lot of features. I am just not sure if I need them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your protocol involves very (very very) simple "commands", then I think the draft you have about your protocol makes sense.

The truth is that there is not a "correct" response. My experience has tougth me that it is better to use what is already there (like JMS, as I mentioned in a comment to your question) rather than trying to create a simpler solution, sometimes it is deceiving thinking that existent solutions are too complicated and we could do it simpler. Believe me, you will encounter problems that you didn't see at the beginning of your design, and use more time that initially estimated.

But, maybe you have a very good idea, so, follow your programmer's instinct and have your own experience ;-)

Comment: Thanks. It is very likely that I am missing something. Could you give a few examples of future problems I am missing that JMS can solve ?

Comment: @Michael not nessesarily something that JMS could solve, but from the top of my head, have you considered: How to modify your protocol if you realise later that you need more parameters? what if one "parameter" turns out to have a non-atomic value (like, for instance, an array)? what if one of the workers has a problem, gets stuck and never reports its status again to the server? does the server have to "ping" every now and then its workers? what if the machine where your server is running needs to be shut down and you need to start a new server in another machine (with other URL or IP)?

Comment: Thaks. All your questions are valid. I will think of them.